# Hide project name in URL in ASP.NET MVC 5 in production enviroment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, routes

What is the best way to remove project name from the URL in production enviroment? 
Path www.mySite.com/controllerName/action changes into 
www.mySite.com/projectName/controllerName/action and it breaks routing.

Modification of context.Request.PathBase doesn't seems to work as it is recommended for MVC 6.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use attribute routing over the controller.
just put on controller [Route("controllerName/action ")]